# Saving image to localstorage - canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm using html5 storage to store my image.
It works great in chrome. In FireFox it works 8/10 times.

```
function getBase64Image(img) {
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;

        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

        console.log("line 1 : " + img.src);
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
        console.log("line 2 : " + dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(jpeg);base64,/, ""));
        return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(jpeg);base64,/, "");
    }
```

Sometimes it returns only "data,".

I see that the canvas size is 0x0:

```
canvas.width = img.width;
canvas.height = img.height;
```

Why is that happening?

Comment: `If the height or width of the canvas is 0, the string "data:," is returned.`, could this be the issue?

Comment: No, I'm loading a good images, Also I see that the first line is ok, and the problem is after the replace

Comment: Can you provide a plnkr or similar to reproduce this?

Comment: Sorry, now I see that var dataURL return a bad result even before the replace

Comment: @Rouby you are right the canvas size is 0x0 sometimes. Do you know why is that ?

Comment: Do you specify width and height in the img elements?

Comment: It's getting it automatically , found the problem thanks to you.
The javascript trying to get the size before it's loaded so sometimes it's not working.

Comment: I will add this solution then as an answer for you to mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the height or width of the canvas is 0, the string "data:," is returned.

This is most likely the cause for some images to fail to receive a proper dataUrl.

Check your `img` elements and/or scripts to obtain and set the width and height of the canvas.

The auto width and height are only available after the image is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

The function is trying to get the height/width before the image is loaded so I get 0x0. To solve that add **img.onload** before calling the save function.

```
function readURL(input, image, width, height) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {

                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    //Save the image
                    var img = new Image();
                    img.src = e.target.result;
                    img.onload = function (e){
                        if (image.id == 'photo1') {
                            save(img, 'image1');
                        }
                        else {
                            save(img, 'image2');
                        }
                    }
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }
```